# Python converts "5.4" but but not "5.4.4" to a float, whats going on here?

Tags: python, type-conversion, syntax-error

Im writing a script that does through rpm packages and im trying to compare the release version of the package with two arguments supplied on the command line, --fromVersion and --toVersion.

I run the script this way:

```
python packageSearch.py --package --fromVersion 5.5.0 --toVersion 7.0.0
```

It semes like even if i try to convert the command-line argument to a string i get the following:

```
if ( float(package['version']) >= float(options.fromVersion) and package['version'] <= options.toVersion ): 

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 7.0.21
```

I searched through stackoverflow and google but i was surprised that i didnt find any good examples of comparing an int to a float, or if the user types in a float it has to be comparing a float to a float.

I also tried without converting and then it works but the compare is wrong.

Why is python saying invalid syntax in this statement:

```
version3 = 5.5.5
File "<stdin>", line 1
version3 = 5.5.5
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but if i try the following:

```
version3 = 5.5
```

it works without problems as expected. What is going on here, why cant i assign 5.5.5 to the variable, and what is the best way of comparing a value that could be an integer or a float with another float, since converting it to a float with float() doesnt seem to work.

Comment: A float cannot have multiple decimal points. The problem is that you use the wrong datatype ("float") for your version.

Comment: The dots in version numbers aren't decimal points. `1.9` > `1.13` for floats but `1.9` < `1.13` for versions. A version is a sequence of integers and you compare them lexicographically, integer by integer (rather than digit by digit).

Comment: What do you think a `float` **is**? **Why** do you expect this conversion to work? Exactly what **value** do you expect the resulting `float` to have?

Comment: first of all i expected it to not do anything if it was already a float but if it was an integer on the command line i would expect it to convert it to a float since according to the documenation it should be converting it, but there seems to be a misunderstanding in the functionality of float() itself, what the datatype is capable to do and the decimal notation itself because 5.552.121,10 would be a valid number where i live

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`distutils.version`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version):

```
>>> from distutils.version import StrictVersion
>>> fromVersion="5.5.0"
>>> toVersion="7.0.0"
>>> if ( StrictVersion(fromVersion) < StrictVersion(toVersion) ):
...   print "From is less than to version"
... 
From is less than to version
>>>
```

EDIT: Saying `pydoc distutils.version` gives a somewhat better documentation in comparison to what's available at [`distutils.version`](http://docs.python.org/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.version).

Comment: That's the way to go!

Comment: This seems like to be exactly what i need, i think ill read a little about the distutils as well seems like an interesting package

Comment: when browsing http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/ and checking distutils.version there is no information on the usage of this module and there is documenation for every other module in the distutils package, where do i find all the classes and some basic usage documenation? I dont find it on the guides at python.org, google or similar

Comment: @user2959896 Maybe [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0386/) PEP would give you the information that you seem to be looking for.

Comment: thanks, that seems to at least explain something. wierd that they dont have a complete api of all the different functions. in one way i like pythons doc but in another way im used to the jav apis with a compact list which is easily to look at and use

Comment: @user2959896 You could say `pydoc distutils.version` and that'd  give you help on the `distutils.version` module.  It's somewhat elaborate in comparison to what's mentioned on http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/

Answer (score 14):

But "5.5.0" is *not* a float. Why would you expect Python to be able to convert it to one? Versions are not simple decimal numbers, and any element of the version can be greater than 10: eg "5.11.35" is a perfectly valid version.

You need to split the variable up into three seperate integers, and compare them individually.

Comment: in my country this is valid 1.000.121,12 so thats why i expected it to work since when thinking float im thinking decimal and that is valid decimal notation where i come from. I expected it to convert to a float because thats what the float version is suppose to do according to documenation. I thought of a version number as just another number.

Answer (score 2):

Store versions in tuples instead of floats, they compare well:

```
assert (1,2,0) < (1,3,0)
assert (0,10) < (0,10,1)
assert (0,10) < (1,0)
assert (0,9) < (0,11)
```

I can see some possible gotchas with this approach though:

```
assert (1,2) == (1,2,0) # Boom!
```